# global variables are always undefined even though async function tries to set them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to multiple MongoDB Databases using mongoose. Therefore, I am following the suggested steps mentioned in their [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections).

In order to keep things clean, I've created a `connectionManager.js` file that takes care of connecting to the different databases and modeling the schemas to the according connections. On top of that, **it stores the created connections and modeled schemas**.

**The code looks like this:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const AccountSchema = require("../models/Account")
const ProfileInformationSchema = require("../models/ProfileInformation")
const BlacklistedTokenSchema = require("../models/BlacklistedToken")
const SessionSchema = require("../models/Session")
const TokenPairSchema = require("../models/TokenPair")

var authConnection
var accountConnection

var AccountModel
var ProfileInformationModel
var BlacklistedTokensModel
var SessionModel
var TokenPairModel

const establishConnections = async (callback) => {
    try {
        authConnection = await mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_AUTH_URI || "myconnString", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        accountConnection = await mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_ACCOUNT_URI || "myconnString", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

        AccountModel = accountConnection.model("accounts", AccountSchema)
        ProfileInformationModel = accountConnection.model("profileInformations", ProfileInformationSchema)

        BlacklistedTokensModel = authConnection.model("blacklistedTokens", BlacklistedTokenSchema)
        SessionModel = authConnection.model('sessions', SessionSchema)
        TokenPairModel = authConnection.model("generatedTokenPairs", TokenPairSchema)

        console.log("Successfully connected to the database")
        callback()
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to the database:", error)
        process.exit(500)
    }
}

module.exports = { authConnection, accountConnection, establishConnections, AccountModel, ProfileInformationModel, BlacklistedTokensModel, SessionModel, TokenPairModel }
```

> **EDIT:** The `establishConnections` function is executed upon startup of the Node.js app, even before the server itself is created. The
>   server will only be created once the connections have successfully
>   been established. Therefore, the ***variables should be set***
>   whenever the first request is handled.

However, when I try to use one of these established connections to create a transaction, I'll get an **error that the according connection would be undefined** (although I set it in code; see code above). This is the code of my `signup` route:

```
const connectionManager = require("../helper/connectionManager");

router.post("/signUp/", checkSignupBodyData, async (req, res, next) => {

    try {

        var transactionSession = await connectionManager.accountConnection.startSession() // Cannot read property 'startSession' of undefined
        await transactionSession.withTransaction(async (tSession) => {
            // transaction code - removed for brevity
        })
        await transactionSession.endSession()

        return res.status(201).json({ message: "The user has been created!" })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 11000 || error.code === 11001) {
            return next(new API_Error(409, "The user has already been created. Please try to login."))
        }
        console.log(error)
        return next(error)
    }
})
```

I really have no idea why I get that error. I debugged the `establishConnections` method inside `connectionManager.js` and can confirm that both the `authConnection` and the `accountConnection` variables are assigned the according connection.

Somehow, the value is undefined when I try to access it in my `signup` route. I would be extremely glad for any help I could get on this matter.

**Also, I've spent too much time on this issue already and am pretty sure that it's just a tiny mistake... but my eyes aren't able to find anything anymore...**

Thanks in advance guys. Stay safe.

Comment: Your function does set the local variables in the module scope. It does not reassign the properties of the `module.exports` object, which are still `undefined`.

Comment: Also it's unclear from the code you posted whether/where `establishConnections` is actually called.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your response. You are right, it's unclear from where the code is called. It is called directly upon startup of the node.js app, even before the server is created. Also, what do you suggest in order to fix the problem you described?

Comment: @Bergi question has been updated.

Comment: Write to `module.exports.authConnection` etc, drop the local variables

Comment: Can I just do that from inside the function ? @Bergi

Comment: Yes, you can do the assignments from inside the function.